# Fastest and most reliable way to load contacts in Codename one

Tags: java, codenameone

I'm trying to get all phone contacts into my app as part of registration and I want the contacts to be loaded with images (Non-negotiable).

I used the code below which crashes the app on iOS and very slow on android. What is the best way to load all phone contacts in [Codename one](https://www.codenameone.com)?

Other apps manage to fetch all my contacts in a very short time, so I'm sure this can be done. And why is the code crashing my app on iOS?

```
Image defaultIcon = fontIcon("\ue113", 7, 0xbcbcbc);
try {
    InfiniteProgress progress = new InfiniteProgress();
    progress.setAnimation(fontIcon(FontIcon.FONTICON_SPIN6 + "", 4, 0x12a4f4));
    Dialog ipDlg = progress.showInifiniteBlocking();
    final String[] myContacts = Display.getInstance().getAllContacts(true);
    for (final String contactId : myContacts) {
        Contact contact = Display.getInstance().getContactById(contactId, true, true, true, true, true);
        Hashtable numbers = contact.getPhoneNumbers();
        Enumeration nums = numbers.elements();

        String firstName = contact.getFirstName() != null ? contact.getFirstName() : "";
        String familyName = contact.getFamilyName() != null ? contact.getFamilyName() : "";
        String names = firstName + " " + familyName;
        while (nums.hasMoreElements()) {
            String phoneNumber = (String) nums.nextElement();
            MultiButton multiContact = new MultiButton(names);
            multiContact.setTextLine2(phoneNumber);
            Image img = contact.getPhoto();
            multiContact.setIcon(img != null ? img.scaledWidth(Size(7)) : defaultIcon);
            content.add(multiContact);
        }
    }
    ipDlg.dispose();
} catch (Exception ex) {
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be the fastest way to load the contacts:

```
Contact[] contacts = Display.getInstance().getAllContacts(true, false, false, false, false, false);
```

Once the contacts are loaded you can bring the images lazily upon request. E.g.:

```
new Thread(() -> { 
    Contact[] cnts = Display.getInstance().getAllContacts(true, false, true, false, false, false); 
    for (int i = 0; i < cnts.length; i++) { 
        Contact cnt = cnts[i]; 
        Image pic = cnt.getPhoto(); 
        if(pic != null) { 
           contactsPics.put(cnt.getId(), pic); 
        } 
    } 
}).start();
```

Comment: Thanks Chen, but how do I load the images lazily and cache them please? Since I still have to loop through all the contacts.

Comment: new Thread(() -> {
            Contact[] cnts = Display.getInstance().getAllContacts(true, false, true, false, false, false);
            for (int i = 0; i < cnts.length; i++) {
                Contact cnt = cnts[i];
                Image pic = cnt.getPhoto();
                if (pic != null) {
                    contactsPics.put(cnt.getId(), pic);
                }
            }
        }).start();